# Atlas Search works too slow when using facet

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, search-engine, mongodb-atlas

I have a big collection (over 22M records, approx. 25GB) on an M10 cluster with MongoDB version 4.4.10. I set up an Atlas search index on one field (address) and it works pretty fast when I request through the search tester. However, when I try to paginate it by specifying a facet, it gets extremely slow in comparison with the query without the facet. Is there a way to optimize the facet or somehow replace the facet with one that works faster ? Below are the plain query and another one with the facet:

```
db.getCollection("users").aggregate([{
    $search: {
      index: 'address',
      text: {
        query: '7148 BIG WOODS DR',
        path: {
          'wildcard': '*'
        }
      }
    }
}]);
```

```
db.getCollection("users").aggregate([{
    $search: {
      index: 'address',
      text: {
        query: '7148 BIG WOODS DR',
        path: {
          'wildcard': '*'
        }
      }
    }
}, {
  $facet: {
    paginatedResult: [
      {
        $limit: 50
      },
      {
        $skip: 0
      }
    ],
    totalCount: [
      {
        $count: 'total'
      }
    ]
  }
}]);
```

Comment: The query without facet, shows only first 50 results (most GUI shows first 50 results by default) and it "seems" very fast. Try to put `.forEach(doc => count +=1)` to iterate over all documents and it will be slow too. The query with facet, `{$count: 'total'}` is very slow since it scans all documents.

Comment: Also note that the second query will scan all 22 million documents each time a page is requested.

Comment: @Joe Shouldn't $count rely on index? There is no need to scan documents really.

Comment: The index scan can't be both. Either it counts and returns no documents, or it returns documents.  Try running with `explain` to see if it will give you details.

Comment: @Joe I would if I had the db. I don't, hence the question. If I understand the "totalCount" facet has noting but $count aggregator. It should be enough to use results of index search from previous stage there, no? Just curious.

Comment: @Valijon true, I just tried that, but I also tried to paginate without the count part, still slow. I guess it calculates the count anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The fast and recommend way is using facet with the [`$searchMeta`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/facet/) stage to retrieve metadata results only for the query

```
 "$searchMeta": {
      "index":"search_index_with_facet_fields",
      "facet":{
         "operator":{
            "compound":{
               "must":[
                  {
                     "text":{
                        "query":"red shirt",
                        "path":{
                           "wildcard":"*"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "compound":{
                        "filter":[
                           {
                              "text":{
                                 "query":["clothes"],
                                 "path":"category"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "text":{
                                 "query":[
                                    "maroon",
                                    "blackandred",
                                    "blackred",
                                    "crimson",
                                    "burgandy",
                                    "burgundy"
                                 ],
                                 "path":"color"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "facets":{
            "brand":{
               "type":"string",
               "path":"brand"
            },
            "size":{
               "type":"string",
               "path":"size"
            },
            "color":{
               "type":"string",
               "path":"color"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here we are fetching 3 facets `brand`, `size`, and `color`, which we need to be defined in your search_index as Facet fields such as

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "category": [
        {
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "brand": [
        {
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "type": "stringFacet"
        }
      ],
      "size": [
        {
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "type": "stringFacet"
        }
      ],
      "color": [
        {
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "type": "stringFacet"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`category` is defined only as `string` since we are not using it in facets but only as a filter field.

We can also replace `filter` op with `must` or `should` based on our requirement.

Finally, we will get [image] as our result.

*p.s. I am also new to mongo and got to this solution after searching a lot, so please upvote if you find it useful, also let me know if there is any error/improvement you notice. Thanks *